# How to deactivate while replacing one activity with a new one

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to have two versions of my program, but how would I have the basic activities be either disabled or not respond to intents, so the more advanced one can do it?

Basically, I want the user to download the basic one, then, if they get the advanced version then it will use the new activities.

**UPDATE:**

After writing a long comment to one answer I thought I would put it here, perhaps more clearly.

Ideally it would be nice to have more `Activities` that other programs could use, so, for example, if there was a program that usees the Twitter API that was being used to allow games to be played, then, there could be a version of the application that allows some advanced functionality, so, by upgrading the application all the games using it would also get the new options, so work better.

It may be as simple as having three versions of the program.

1. Basic version.
2. Plus version to upgrade from basic
   version.
3. Initial install of the plus version.

I would still have a problem with (2), and I can't just have it upgrade the jar file since most of the code between version (1) and (3) would be the same, but the Activity that may change could look to see if there is a better version, and either do nothing, or pass the Intent on to the new Activity.  If it did nothing, then it would assume the plus version would also pick up on the Intent and handle it.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a stretch but... could your basic app, upon receiving an intent, check to see if there is an instance of the advanced app installed via [getInstalledApplications()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29) from the PackageManager and if it is installed, send a custom intent to launch the advanced app?

Comment: This could work, I never considered that.  The only difficulty, which may not be an issue is that ideally we should eventually have lots of Activities that others can use,so we don't have to keep reinventing the wheel, so if someone has an advanced version then that would be used by all the applications. For example, if you have a Twitter activity, games may use Twitter, and there may be an advanced option that just by upgrading one application will improve all the games using it.  But, for a single application your idea is fantastic.